# Cyrillic text is not displayed under \paragraph (with KOMA-Script)

Tags: xetex, miktex, koma-script

I'v got problems with KOMA-Script and cyrillic (I guess).

Commands `\paragraph` (as well as `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.) don't display russian text. Is this a known issue?

I am using SublimeText, LatexTools, MikTeX and Sumatra

```
\documentclass[fontsize=5,parskip=never]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper,landscape, left=1mm, top=4mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{multicol}       

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing% одинарный интервал

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % or \setlist{noitemsep} to leave space around whole list

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}


\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
%\usepackage{fontspec}              % otf шрифты
\usepackage{textpos}                % текстовые блоки
%\usepackage[export]{adjustpage}        % положение картинок 
\usepackage{xcolor}                 % цвет





\begin{document}




\begin{multicols*}{5}

\Large \textbf{Flush Shutter DC} \normalsize 



\large \textbf{Электробезопасность} \normalsize     %% I SEE THIS (TEXTBF WORKS WELL)
\paragraph{ПАРАГРАФ}                                %% I DONT SEE THIS
\paragraph{PARAGRAPH}                               %% I SEE THIS

text


\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your log will show `Missing character: There is no П in font [lmsans10-bold]:+tlig;!`   You need to specify a heading font with support for Cyrillic

Comment: do not use `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста` with xetex, neither `inputenc` nor `fontenc` should be used here. (although they are not the cause of the problem here)

Answer (score 5):

The document is using latin modern bold sans serif for titles and that font does not have Cyrillic.

The log warns

```
Missing character: There is no П in font [lmsans10-bold]:+tlig;!
```

You could select a different font using the classes heading setup features or generally avoid the problem with the `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles` option.

In this case you still get sans titles as you have specified Arial as the main document font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=5,
  parskip=never,
  egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper,landscape, left=1mm, top=4mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{multicol}       

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing% одинарный интервал

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep} % or \setlist{noitemsep} to leave space around whole list

\usepackage[russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}


%\usepackage{fontspec}              % otf шрифты
\usepackage{textpos}                % текстовые блоки
%\usepackage[export]{adjustpage}        % положение картинок 
\usepackage{xcolor}                 % цвет





\begin{document}



\begin{multicols*}{5}

\subsection*{Flush Shutter DC}

\subsection*{Электробезопасность}    %% I SEE THIS (TEXTBF WORKS WELL)
\paragraph{ПАРАГРАФ}                                %% I DONT SEE THIS
\paragraph{PARAGRAPH}                               %% I SEE THIS

text


\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For koma  v3.39 or newer there is now the class option `sfdefaults=false` instead of `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and they call that progress?

Comment: I'm also very disappointed, who should remember such a boring name like `sfdefaults`  :)

Answer (score 3):

You are just forgetting to set the sans serif font:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы

% settings
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Flush Shutter DC}

\textbf{Электробезопасность}

\paragraph{ПАРАГРАФ}

\paragraph{PARAGRAPH}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]